# Which is the correct sentence?

Tags: sentence

Which is the correct sentence?

> 1) This is the first time that I have ever **eaten** mushroom soup.
>
> 2) This is the first time that I have ever **drunk** mushroom soup.

Comment: In other words, does one speak of _eating_ or _drinking_ soup? There is no hard-and-fast rule - it could depend on whether the soup is thick or thin, and whether it is in a bowl or a mug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both could be correct. It depends on how chunky the mushrooms are and how thick the soup is. To avoid the issue, you could say, *"This is the first time that I've ever **had** mushroom soup"*.

Comment: Or even *consumed*

Comment: Or ever *enjoyed*, *suffered* or *survived* mushroom soup.